# How to get sum of repeated rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get weight of order, so I need to sum my results
This table looks like this

```
SalesOrderID SalesOrderDetailID SubTotal              CompanyName                                                                                                                      Weight
------------ ------------------ --------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
71774        110562             880,3484              Good Toys                                                                                                                        1061.40
71774        110563             880,3484              Good Toys                                                                                                                        988.83
71776        110567             78,81                 West Side Mart                                                                                                                   317.00
71780        110616             38418,6895            Nearby Cycle Shop                                                                                                                5098.36
71780        110617             38418,6895            Nearby Cycle Shop                                                                                                                24874.88
71780        110618             38418,6895            Nearby Cycle Shop                                                                                                                78053.76
71780        110619             38418,6895            Nearby Cycle Shop                                                                                                                2431.24
71780        110620             38418,6895            Nearby Cycle Shop                                                                                                                12596.19
```

The query:

```
SELECT a.SalesOrderID, c.SalesOrderDetailID, a.SubTotal,b.CompanyName,
(SELECT c.OrderQty*d.Weight WHERE c.SalesOrderID=c.SalesOrderID) AS Weight
FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader as a
INNER JOIN SalesLT.Customer AS b
ON a.CustomerID=b.CustomerID
INNER JOIN SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail AS c
ON c.SalesOrderID=a.SalesOrderID
INNER JOIN SalesLT.Product as d
ON d.ProductID=c.ProductID
```

I've tried to make sum as sum(case when) but this gets me an error
Is there any other method?
Expected output:
71774 | 880,3484  |  Good Toys | 2050,23

2050,23 is a sum of two rows of weight

Comment: Have a look at `GROUP BY`

Comment: can you please share your expected output

Comment: @LearnHadoop I attached output

Comment: 71774 | 880 | Good Toys | 2049 -how did you arrive 2049. can you please explain it

Comment: @LearnHadoop 1061+988

Comment: `Subtotal` looks like you are storing delimited data in it; that is a fundamental design flaw and you should really be working to normalise your design. Also use *meaningful* aliases. "a" is for `SalesOrderheader`? "b" is for `Customer`? There isn't a single letter *b* in the word "Customer", so why alias it as "b"? [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: `WHERE c.SalesOrderID=c.SalesOrderID` seems odd as well. The *only* time `c.SalesOrderID` *can't* equal itself is when it has the value `NULL` so why not just `WHERE c.SalesOrderID IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: what is wrong with Subtotal ?

Comment: suggest you clarify if the decimal separator is a comma where you live - some people try to store string lists as comma separated in databases (which is the point from Larnu above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
WITH TMP_TABLE AS
(
    SELECT
        a.SalesOrderID,
        c.SalesOrderDetailID,
        a.SubTotal,
        b.CompanyName,
        (c.OrderQty * d.Weight) AS Weight
    FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader as a
    INNER JOIN SalesLT.Customer AS b ON a.CustomerID=b.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail AS c ON c.SalesOrderID=a.SalesOrderID
    INNER JOIN SalesLT.Product as d ON d.ProductID=c.ProductID
)
SELECT SalesOrderId,
    SubTotal,
    CompanyName,
    SUM(Weight)
FROM TMP_TABLE
GROUP BY SalesOrderId,
    SubTotal,
    CompanyName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SalesOrderId,SUM(Weight) SumOfOrderWeights
FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail
GROUP BY SalesOrderId
ORDER BY SalesOrderId
```

Answer (score 0):

your data

```
declare @a table(
   SalesOrderID       INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,SalesOrderDetailID INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,SubTotal            VARCHAR(60)  NOT NULL
  ,CompanyName        VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
  ,Weight            float NOT NULL
 
);
INSERT INTO @a
(SalesOrderID,SalesOrderDetailID,SubTotal,CompanyName,Weight) VALUES 
(71774,110562,'880,3484','Good Toys',1061.40),
(71774,110563,'880,3484','Good Toys',988.83),
(71776,110567,'78,81','West Side Mart',317.00),
(71780,110616,'38418,6895','Nearby Cycle Shop',5098.36),
(71780,110617,'38418,6895','Nearby Cycle Shop',24874.88),
(71780,110618,'38418,6895','Nearby Cycle Shop',78053.76),
(71780,110619,'38418,6895','Nearby Cycle Shop',2431.24),
(71780,110620,'38418,6895','Nearby Cycle Shop',12596.19);
```

your query

```
select SalesOrderID,SubTotal,CompanyName,sum(Weight) Weight from @a
where CompanyName='Good Toys'  --removing filter
group by SalesOrderID,SubTotal,CompanyName
```